# kubelet Error while processing event /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/libcontainer_10010_systemd_test_default.slice

Tags: kubernetes

I have setup Kubernetes 1.15.3 cluster on Centos 7 OS using systemd cgroupfs. on all my nodes syslog started logging this message frequently.

How to fix this error message?

`kubelet: W0907 watcher.go:87 Error while processing event ("/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/libcontainer_10010_systemd_test_default.slice": 0x40000100 == IN_CREATE|IN_ISDIR): readdirent: no such file or directory`

Thanks

Comment: Any update on this issue

Comment: I have upgraded containerd to `1.4.6` version. Now I don't get this error message

Answer (score 1):

It's a [known issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/76531) with a bad interaction with `runc`; someone observed it is actually *caused* by [a repeated etcd health check](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/76531#issuecomment-522286281) but that wasn't my experience on Ubuntu, which exhibits that same behavior on *every* Node

They allege that updating the `runc` binary on your hosts will make the problem go away, but I haven't tried that myself

Comment: I will test this and update the status. Thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem with the same kubernetes version and with the same context -that is changing cgroups to systemd. Github ticket for this error is created [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/56850).

After changing container runtime, as it is described in this [tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/#docker) to `systemd` error start popping out in kublete service log.

What worked for me was to update `docker` and `containerd` to following versions.

```
docker: v19.03.5
containerd: v1.2.10
```

**I assume that any version higher than above will fix the problem as well.**